# How to install vim which is cloned from github.com?

Tags: github, vim

I've cloned it but I didn't find any .exe file, Nor do i see it in programs list in Control Panel of windows. I'am a bit confused as to what cloning means. I know that there is direct download .exe file on vim.org website. Its for sure that I'am beginner for all these. Please help. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

reading the "installation" section found in the *README.md* of the [vim repo](https://github.com/vim/vim), you can see the filenames containing the instructions that will help you with the installation, depending on your OS.

```
README_ami.txt      Amiga
README_unix.txt     Unix
README_dos.txt      MS-DOS and MS-Windows
README_mac.txt      Macintosh
README_haiku.txt    Haiku
README_vms.txt      VMS
```

So, for the full information I suggest you go to those files, or go to the [vim website](https://www.vim.org/download.php) where there is also good information about the installation.

Anyway, I will briefly explain below the information that those files and the vim website say for most common operating systems

## If you're on Unix:

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
```

## If you're on Mac

> The Macintosh binaries are not on the Vim ftp site. They are produced by a few Macintosh lovers. Often they lag behind a few versions.
>
> MacVim has more a Mac look and feel, is developed actively and most people prefer this version. Most of MacVim was made by Björn Winckler.
>
> MacVim can be downloaded here: [link](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim)

Or if you prefer, here is the [MacVim homepage](https://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/).

## If you're on Windows:

The next instructions were copied from [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/READMEdir/README_dos.txt).

**Option A: Using the self-installing .exe**

Go to [vim.org/download.php](https://www.vim.org/download.php) and click on *self-installing executable* (or just [click here](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim82.exe)) and follow the prompts.

Watch out for:

- When an existing installation is detected, you are offered to first remove
  this.  The uninstall program is then started while the install program waits
  for it to complete.  Sometimes the windows overlap each other, which can be
  confusing.  Be sure the complete the uninstalling before continuing the
  installation.  Watch the taskbar for uninstall windows.
- When selecting a directory to install Vim, use the same place where other
  versions are located.  This makes it easier to find your _vimrc file.  For
  example "C:\Program Files\vim" or "D:\vim".  A name ending in "vim" is
  preferred.
- After selecting the directory where to install Vim, clicking on "Next" will
  start the installation.

**Option B: Using .zip files**

1. Go to the directory where you want to put the Vim files.  Examples:
   cd C:\
   cd D:\editors
   If you already have a "vim" directory, go to the directory in which it is
   located.  Check the $VIM setting to see where it points to:
   set VIM
   For example, if you have
   C:\vim\vim82
   do
   cd C:\
   Binary and runtime Vim archives are normally unpacked in the same location,
   on top of each other.
2. Unpack the zip archives.  This will create a new directory "vim\vim82",
   in which all the distributed Vim files are placed.  Since the directory
   name includes the version number, it is unlikely that you overwrite
   existing files.
   Examples:
   pkunzip -d gvim82.zip
   unzip vim82w32.zip

   You need to unpack the runtime archive and at least one of the binary
   archives.  When using more than one binary version, be careful not to
   overwrite one version with the other, the names of the executables
   "vim.exe" and "gvim.exe" are the same.

   After you unpacked the files, you can still move the whole directory tree
   to another location.  That is where they will stay, the install program
   won't move or copy the runtime files.
3. Change to the new directory:
   cd vim\vim82
   Run the "install.exe" program.  It will ask you a number of questions about
   how you would like to have your Vim setup.  Among these are:

   - You can tell it to write a "_vimrc" file with your preferences in the
     parent directory.
   - It can also install an "Edit with Vim" entry in the Windows Explorer
     popup menu.
   - You can have it create batch files, so that you can run Vim from the
     console or in a shell.  You can select one of the directories in your
     $PATH.  If you skip this, you can add Vim to the search path manually:
     The simplest is to add a line to your autoexec.bat.  Examples:
     set path=%path%;C:\vim\vim82
     set path=%path%;D:\editors\vim\vim82
   - Create entries for Vim on the desktop and in the Start menu.

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Vim is *open source software*, and its *source code*, i.e. all the technical files that make up Vim is (nowadays) hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim).

**Cloning** that repository means you'll download all of those files to your computer (and with Git as the underlying revision control system, you'll even get the full history of all changes ever done). As Vim supports a very big set of very diverse platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac, ...), the repository itself does not (and should not) contain pre-built *binaries*, nor a full *installer* that most users expect to run. So, unless you have the intention to actively contribute to Vim by submitting bug fixes or enhancements, you don't need to *clone* or do anything with GitHub. If you do want to get technical, [src/INSTALLpc.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALLpc.txt) contains the instructions for building Vim on Windows. This includes choosing a compiler, installing it and the required dependencies, configuring the build, building, and then finally copying the files to a permanent location on your PC, either manually or by building and then running an installer.

For plain passive consumption of Vim (which is rewarding in itself, but may even lead you to eventually also programming it), the [**Downloading Vim**](https://www.vim.org/download.php) page on [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/) has all the information that you need, with links to the most popular installers right at the top.

#### a word on versions

For a casual user, using the **latest stable version** is recommended; this is 8.2 right now; [gvim82.exe](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim82.exe) is a corresponding installer for Windows. This offers the best compromise between stability and latest features. In the case of Vim, expect a new release roughly every year.

You'll also find **development builds** (something like 8.2.0740); these usually function as well and have the very latest features under development, but often are less stable. I would use these only if you really need a leading-edge feature, or want to report a bug. You should then probably update very frequently, and from there it's only a small step to actually cloning the repository and building everything on your own!